# Difference between Elastic Search and Google Search Appliance page ranking

Tags: search, elasticsearch, pagerank, google-search-appliance

How does the page ranking in elastic search work. Once we create an index is there an underlying intelligent layer that creates a metadata repository and provides results to query based on relevance. I have created several indices and I want to know how the results are ordered once a query is provided. And is there a way to influence these results based on relationships between different records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean how documents are scored in elasticsearch? Or are you talking about the 'page-rank' in elasticsearch?

Documents are scored based on how well the query matches the document. This approach is based on the TF-IDF concept [term frequency–inverse document frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf). There is, however, no 'page-rank' in elasticsearch. The 'page-rank' takes into consideration how many documents point towards a given document. A document with many in-links is weighted higher than other. This is meant to reflect the fact whether a document is authoritative or not.

In elasticsearch, however, the relations between the documents are not taken into account when it comes to scoring.